# MySQL table definition has changed error when reading from a table that has been written to by PySpark

Tags: python, mysql, apache-spark, pyspark

I am currently working on a data pipeline with pyspark. As part of the pipeline, I write a spark dataframe to mysql using the following function:

```
def jdbc_insert_overwrite_table(df, mysql_user, mysql_pass, mysql_host, mysql_port, mysql_db, num_executors, table_name,
                                logger):
    mysql_url = "jdbc:mysql://{}:{}/{}?characterEncoding=utf8".format(mysql_host, mysql_port, mysql_db)
    logger.warn("JDBC Writing to table " + table_name)
    df.write.format('jdbc')\
        .options(
        url=mysql_url,
        driver='com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver',
        dbtable=table_name,
        user=mysql_user,
        password=mysql_pass,
        truncate=True,
        numpartitions=num_executors,
        batchsize=100000
    ).mode('Overwrite').save()
```

This works with no issue. However, later on in the pipeline (within the same PySpark app/ spark session), this table is a dependency for another transformation, and I try reading from this table using the following function:

```
def read_mysql_table_in_session_df(spark, mysql_conn, query_str, query_schema):
    cursor = mysql_conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query_str)
    records = cursor.fetchall()
    df = spark.createDataFrame(records, schema=query_schema)
    return df
```

And I get this MySQL error: `Error 1412: Table definition has changed, please retry transaction.`

I've been able to resolve this by closing and ping(reconnect=True) to the database, but I don't like this solution as it feels like a band-aid.

Any ideas why I'm getting this error? I've confirmed writing to the table does not change the table definition (schema wise, at least).

Comment: The problem is due to reading and writing at the same time well it looks like the processing is sequential ( the first task which is writing will be finished then spark will treat the second process ) however it is not, I advise you to save the table using  another name and then make the last process in the new table name.

Comment: one suggestion would be to cache the dataframe before saving it as table and use that dataframe again for your remaining logic instead of reading it again from the table. Also you are overwriting the table so that it is only inserting the records that are in the dataframe. If your dataframe size is huge you can use it without caching and that should also work.